# Allow HTML Tags Through Axios Request from Vue to Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I have a text area as below:

```
 <textarea class="from-control" name="body" id="body"  v-html="pageForm.body" v-model="pageForm.body" rows="5" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    
    export default {
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          pageForm: new Form({
            body: '',
          }),
        };
      },
      props: [],
      mounted() {
       
      },
      methods: {
        update() {
          let loader = this.$loading.show();
          this.pageForm.patch('/api/frontend/google-map/')
              .then(response => {
               
                toastr.success(response.message);
                loader.hide();
              })
              .catch(error => {
                loader.hide();
                helper.showErrorMsg(error);
              });
        },
      }
    }
    </script>
```

I am sending an `<iframe>` from the `<textarea>` via axios patch request as `<iframe src="some url"></iframe>`

But in the laravel controller I receive `$request->body = ""`

Any ideas how do I achieve this?

Note:Form binding is working fine, but get empty value in Laravel Controller
[image]

Comment: `this.pageForm.patch` ? is this possible ? i never tried this i use axios or fetch to do api calls

Comment: yes it is possible